# Is it possible to tell Xorg not to listen on the abstract socket

Tags: xorg

On Linux (in recent versions), Xorg listens on both a Unix domain socket on the filesystem (`/tmp/.X11-unix/X<n>`) and in the *abstract* domain (shown as `@/tmp/.X11-unix/X<n>` in netstat output).

It also listens on TCP (port `6000 + <n>`).

One can stop it from listening on TCP by adding a `-nolisten tcp`, but how can we tell it not to listen on the abstract namespace?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer while I was writing the question, so I might as well post both in case that's some help to someone.

```
X -nolisten abstract
```

is accepted but doesn't work.

```
X -nolisten local
```

seems to work. I would have expected that one to disable all Unix domain sockets, but it doesn't. It disables the abstract namespace one only.

As noted by [@imz--IvanZakharyaschev](/users/4319), and as confirmed by reading the code (https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libxtrans/tree/Xtrans.c?id=c4262efc9688e495261d8b23a12f956ab38e006f#n99 -> https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libxtrans/tree/Xtranssock.c?id=c4262efc9688e495261d8b23a12f956ab38e006f#n2532), to disable Unix-domain sockets, it's `-nolisten unix`.

Comment: is this only an academic question, or does it have practical use (not to listen on the abstract socket)?

Comment: @MartinVegter, not sure now. It could have been because I wanted to capture the X11 protocol traffic from an application, and it's harder to do when it's done over an abstract socket.

Comment: @MartinVegter, another use case is making the X server socket accessible from a container

Comment: It's `-nolisten unix` to disable the Unix domain sockets in the filesystem, isnt't? https://tstarling.com/blog/2016/06/x11-security-isolation/ : "You can use the X server command line parameter `-nolisten local` to prevent your X server from listening on the abstract socket. The UNIX socket transport (called “unix” in the X command line) will still be enabled, and all applications will use it instead."

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev, yes, you're right.

Comment: Another reason to disable the abstract socket is that abstract sockets live in the network namespace and thus it's rather harder to prevent access to them than it is to prevent access to filesystem sockets, using sandboxing applications.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the already given answer. If you want to apply this change to your system, consider looking at these files:

For plain "xinit": `/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc`:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp -nolisten local "$@"
```

For "lightdm": `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-X-no-listen.conf`

```
[Seat:*]
xserver-command=X -nolisten tcp -nolisten local
```

All credits go to this blog post: https://tstarling.com/blog/2016/06/x11-security-isolation/  (Thanks a lot for it!)